# Value of type 'AnimationView?' has no member 'setAnimation'

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I am trying to add an animation to my application using Lottie but I get this error and I still do not know how to solve it.

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var animationView: AnimationView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startAnimation()
    }
    
    func startAnimation(){
        animationView.setAnimation(named: "data")//error1
        animationView.loopAnimation = true//error2
        animationView.play()
    }
}
```

The error that comes out:

> Value of type 'AnimationView?' has no member 'setAnimation'
>
> Value of type 'AnimationView?' has no member 'loopAnimation'

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it seems you are new in swift.

this happen because the class `AnimationView` does not have function named `setAnimation(named:)` or variable named `loopAnimation`, you need to declare them inside  `AnimationView` class

Comment: This answer is unhelpful. He could be using swift package manager or Cocoapods and is just looking for the updated syntax.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using lottie-ios version 3.1.3 and ran into this same issue.  After a little bit of digging I found that the syntax has changed. For your first error you need to change the code to the following:

```
animationView.animation = Animation.named("spineffectloader")
```

For the second error you should change the code to the following:

```
animationView.loopMode = .loop
```